# Does a projection operator commute with an unitary operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space and let $U$ and $A$ be, respectivelly, a unitary and a projection operator, i.e. they satisfy:
$$UU^{*}=U^{*}U = I \quad \mbox{and} \quad A^{*}=A=A^{2}$$

**Question:* Does it follow that $UA=AU$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $U=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ and $A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$. This should work.

Comment: For ease of reference: This counter-example implies that, in general, the operators do not commute.